# Edit must be at least x characters message shows different values

Tags: support, edits, user-interface, error-message

The **at least x characters** limit doesn't match in the validation messages as shown below:

Edit Summary text box validation message:

> Your edit summary must be at least **10** characters

Red highlight pop-up validation message:

> Edits must be at least **6** characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

[image: Screenshot showing both error messages]

Comment: I guess the first message is talking about the summary (the "fix typo" in your example), and the red popup is talking about the post you edited (you changed less than 6 characters in the post's content)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Your edit must be 6 characters - what you want to change in the post
- Your edit summary must be 10 characters, your description of what you want to change in the post so we can understand what you're trying to do.

They are different things and have different limits.

So here you've two separate problems and you're seeing two separate errors.